# Unable to read directory after deploying to vercel

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel

I am building a basic blogging website using NextJS. All of the blog data is stored as JSON in the public directory under a folder called `blogdata`. To get the contents of the blodtata folder, I have created in API route to read the `blogdata` folder then send the data back. here is how it looks:

```js
// pages/api/blogs.ts

import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';


export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  let blogs;
  blogs = await fs.readdir("./public/blogdata/", "utf-8")
  res.status(200).json({ blogs })
}
```

I am using getServerSidePropsfront end this data on the front-end like so:

```js
// pages/index.tsx

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  /**
    ️️️
    */
  let data;
  try {
    if (process.env.ENVIORMENT == "dev") {
      data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/blogs") // ️
      // http://localhost:3000/api/blogs
      data = await data.json() // ️
      console.log(data.blogs) // ️
    }
    else {
      data = await fetch("https://blog-templates-demo.vercel.app/api/blogs") // ️
      console.log(data)
      data = await data.json() // ️
      console.log(data.blogs) // ️
      data = data.blogs
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err) // ️
  }
  return { props: { data } } // ️
}
```

Running yarn dev, it works fine. Here is a screen shot showing it:
[image: yarn dev result]

Now when deploying it to vercel, it seems to give a `500 internal server error` on **my** website.
[image: 500 inetnal server error]

---

Looking at the logs, it says that vercel was unable to find the public/blogdata directory.
[image: error shown on logtail]

This probably means it has something to do with how it works after compiling the code. Would anyone know how I should go about fixing this 500 error?

The site is located at [https://blog-templates-demo.vercel.app](https://github.com/satindar31/blog-templates)
Its code is at https://github.com/satindar31/blog-templates